# Wrong notification on GNOME Shell?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, notification

I just installed GNOME Shell on my 12.04 a couple hours ago.
The notifications are just cool, and I installed shell extensions, and it works smoothly in 1 hour.
Then I restarted my computer for some reason, start back in to GNOME.
And I was surprised with the default notification showed up.
It replaced the GNOME notifications!

[image: Notification]

I tried to:

1. Reinstall `gnome-shell`. <sup>(autoremove and install)</sup>
2. Reset desktop configuration.

But it didn't work at all.
Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Plus: *I got a double notification (osd + gnome notification showed up) when someone chatted me.*

Comment: Please, someone, any help would be appreciated. This is really annoying ( -_-)"

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think this could be related to recent updates as the problem did not start until I installed updates that went out on Wednesday (6/13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you still having this problem? After an update this weekend I was getting Unity and Gnome notifications, sometimes for the same events. Then, I installed updates today and the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: 2 days ago, the problem was fixed right after I restart my system due to system updates. And it worked fine, until I restarted my system the second time. This problem came back to my system. I don't know why. :(

Comment: Oh, I just updated my system again hours ago, and it's now fixed, even with a couple restart, thanks again for your info. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service`, basically it tells the system to open notify-osd if you are using a unity, unity-2d or a gnome-session.

Since I don't have unity, I just replaced both cases to notification-daemon

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get remove libnotify4 libnotify-bin notify-osd` this could remove Unity notification system.

Comment: Oops, something's not right. When I try to run that command, it says a lot of things. There are so much packages to be removed and to be installed. Even `unity`, `nautilus`, and `update-notifier` are to be removed?! Sorry, but I think your answer didn't helped me :(